# context-free shuffle for two-letter alphabets

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, closure-properties

The operation of shuffle takes two words and merges their symbols, keeping the symbols of each of the strings in the right order. It can be recursively defined by $x \parallel \varepsilon = \varepsilon \parallel x = x$ and $ax \parallel by = a (x \parallel by) \cup b (ax \parallel y)$. Here $a,b\in \Sigma$ and $x,y\in \Sigma^*$.
For languages $K\parallel L = \bigcup_{x\in K, y\in L} x\parallel y$.

It is known that the context-free languages are *not* closed under shuffle. An interesting question is raised in a recent arxiv overview paper *Decision Problems on Copying and Shuffling* [2302.06248](https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.06248) by Halava etal.  Do we need more than two symbols for a counter example for shuffling two context-free languages?

> **Problem 6.** Give an example of two context-free languages $L_1, L_2 \subseteq \{ a, b \}^*$ such that $L_1 \parallel L_2$ is not
> context-free.

Comment: The current version of the paper quoted and linked above mentions the example from the accepted answer. Example 3, page 14.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two letters should be sufficient as the following example shows: let
$L_1=\{a^nba^n\mid n\geq1\}$ and $L_2=\{b^nab^n\mid n\geq1\}$. Then we have $$(L_1\|L_2)\cap a^*b^*a^*b^*=\{a^mb^{n+1}a^{m+1}b^n\mid m,n\geq1\}\,.$$
This equation holds, since we can only map the letters of a word from $L_1\subseteq a^*ba^*$ to the first three blocks of $a^*b^*a^*b^*$ and, similarly, the letters of a word from $L_2\subseteq b^*ab^*$ to the last three blocks.

The right-hand side of this equation is not context-free. Since the intersection of a context-free language with a regular language always is context-free, the language $L_1\|L_2$ cannot be context-free.

Comment: Well, that is fun!